# I can't add links to my wordpress theme due to this function creating empty href="#" links

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying for the last two days to figure out how to modify the PHP files on this theme to add some links to some images. I don't know PHP and know very little of programming in general so I am asking for help.

What I've been doing for the last two days:
I searched all the PHP files for the location of this section of the theme. I finally found the section and thought I had solved my problem after finding what looked like the array that the following function pulled it's parameters from.

```
foreach ( $shop_isle_banners_decoded as $shop_isle_banner ) :

                    if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_banner->image_url ) ) {

                        echo '<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="content-box mt-0 mb-0"><div class="content-box-image">';

                        if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_banner->link ) ) {

                            if ( function_exists( 'icl_t' ) && ! empty( $shop_isle_banner->id ) ) {
                                $shop_isle_banner_link = icl_t( 'Banner ' . $shop_isle_banner->id, 'Banner link', $shop_isle_banner->link );
```

I was able to change the images by replacing the asset files but I cannot change the links. I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention that there are three images that this applies to. I need to add three different URLs to the $shop_isle_banner_link

Comment: Are you sure that is the bit of code that causes your problem. Because everything here seems to be fine. I don't know what paramters icl_t() needs. If it only needs one you could try changing the commas in the last line to dots. Nothing else I see there.

Comment: Please share the code of icl_t function if you have.